# Sample rates- which rate should I choose importing files

Tags: sample-rate

I am new to using a DAW. I have been given audio files which have a sample rate of 96 khz. My DAW is asking me if I want to convert to 44.1khz or retain the sample rate of 96khz.

I will need to import vocals over these files which were recorded in 44.1khz and also add new vocals in addition. Does is matter which sample rate I choose to import the 96khz files? If I do not convert them to 44.1khz, will I have trouble importing the vocals which are only 44.1khz?

I am using logic, the latest version. After I have finished the vocals they are going to be sent to a mix engineer. Will they likely want everything at a 44.1khz sample rate? I'd like to know what is standard.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the project and everything at 96kHz. The mastering engineer will down-convert to 44.1 kHz when they do the mastering.

44.1KHz is the Red Book CD standard sampling rate. Still used, although CD isn't used as much these days.